# How to assign a non-indexed array of values to a dataframe, and match index alignment?

Tags: python, pandas, numpy, dataframe

Following, is a *minimal example* of a larger problem. In particular, `f` is a more complex function with the exact signature.

`arr` must be an `array` or `non-null` values.

Passing a `DataFrame` to the function, is not an option.

---

I have a specific column in a DataFrame that contains values and `NaN` values.

```py
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

df = pd.DataFrame({"nums": [1, 2, None, 4, None, 5]})
```

I also have a function that takes a numpy array and returns one, e.g.

```py
def f(a: np.ndarray) -> np.ndarray:
    return a ** 2
```

I can get a numpy array from all `.notnull()` values of the `"nums"` column and apply `f`.

```py
arr = np.array(df[df["nums"].notnull()]["nums"].to_list())
result = f(arr)
```

**Question:** How can append `result` as a new column into the original `df` where all `NaN` values in the original `"nums"` column also get a `NaN` in the result column?

Edit: Maybe to point out that I didn't come unprepared. One solution I have found is

```py
idx = df[df["nums"].notnull()].index
df.loc[idx, "result"] = result
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- Create a [`pandas.Series`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.html) with `result` and `idx`, then add the `Series` to `df` as a column.

```py
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

# setup dataframe
df = pd.DataFrame({"nums": [1, 2, None, 4, None, 5]})

# function
def f(a: np.ndarray) -> np.ndarray:
    return a ** 2

# get non-null values in an array
arr = df.nums.dropna().values

# index of non-null numbers
idx = df[df["nums"].notnull()].index

# call function
result = f(arr)

# make pandas series with idx and result
ser = pd.Series(result, idx)

# add set as a column in df
df['num2'] = ser

# display(df)
   nums  num2
0   1.0   1.0
1   2.0   4.0
2   NaN   NaN
3   4.0  16.0
4   NaN   NaN
5   5.0  25.0
```

Comment: Thanks! I didn't realize you edited your deleted answer instead of writing an entirely new one and I did not check the edits ([I should have known better](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/users/flair/187.png)). Anyway, your answer works perfectly in our use-case.

Comment: @halirutan You're welcome. Glad this works for you.

Answer (score 1):

Use `loc`

```
df.loc[df["nums"].notnull(),'new']=f(arr)
df
   nums   new
0   1.0   1.0
1   2.0   4.0
2   NaN   NaN
3   4.0  16.0
4   NaN   NaN
5   5.0  25.0
```